# Android Automotive Sample App for Navigation

Tags: android, android-automotive

I have found the document on the developer page for building a navigation app [https://developer.android.com/training/cars/apps/navigation](https://How%20to%20build%20navigation%20App)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has published a sample code for a navigation app for Android Automotive
[Sample navigation App](https://github.com/android/car-samples/tree/main/car_app_library/navigation)